# error 503 on cakephp page

Tags: php, cakephp

I uploaded a working version of a webpage on a remote server and this link now is returning a "503 service unavailable". But this only happens with this page. Not sure how  I can solve this, as this is the only webpage out of 20 that does this on the remote server and works fine on my local server.

```
      UPDATE: This error only appears when i try to view a download                                                                                        

     2014-10-01 22:18:02 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class CssController could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'CssController',
  'plugin' => NULL,
)
Request URL: /~aptutori/crm4/css/jquerytablesorterpager.css
Stack Trace:
#0 /home/aptutori/public_html/crm4/app/webroot/index.php(92): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
```

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: Here is the error from app/tmp but the same webpage  works on my local server 2014-10-01 20:09:44 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class CssController could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'CssController',
  'plugin' => NULL,
)
Request URL: /~aptutori/crm4/css/jquerytablesorterpager.css
Stack Trace:
#0 /home/aptutori/public_html/crm4/app/webroot/index.php(92): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup proper [URL redirection](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html).

You most probably didn't copy `.htaccess` to the server or `mod_rewrite` isn't enabled.

Comment: .htaccess was copied over and I only get the error on viewing my download on the remote server.2014-10-01 22:18:02 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class CssController could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'CssController',
  'plugin' => NULL,
)
Request URL: /~aptutori/crm4/css/jquerytablesorterpager.css
Stack Trace:
#0 /home/aptutori/public_html/crm4/app/webroot/index.php(92): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}

Comment: this is my whole .htacces file  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: You seem to be having the site under a subdirectory and/or your host is already using rewrite to point `~aptutori` to your www root, so you will need to set a `RewriteBase /path/to/cake/app` rule inside your `.htaccess` as explained in the link I provided.

Comment: Is this the only thing i add to to .htaccess as it ytalks about rewite engine as well  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /path/to/cake/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>